# Windows form application database: “An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll”

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if ((UserName.Text != "") && (Password.Text != ""))
        {
            string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["The_patients.Properties.Settings.Users1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            string q = "select * from Users where UserName = @Username and Password = @Password ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", this.UserName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", this.Password.Text);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully Done");
                }
            }
            if (dr.HasRows == false)
            { MessageBox.Show("Access Denied, password username mismatched"); }
        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("Enter username and password"); }
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to connect my application to the database , and check the username and password validation but when i run my code and write the username and password it's give me this error i tried to know what is the wrong but i can't find it is there any solution ?

> The error shows here `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);`

App.config

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
 <configSections>
 </configSections>
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="The_patients.Properties.Settings.Users1ConnectionString"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\users\mohammad\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\The patients\The patients\Users1.mdb"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
</configuration>
```

I search too much in google but i didn't find a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an SqlConnection (and all the classes from the Sql Server Client library) but your database is an MS-Access one. You need to use the OleDbConnection and relative OleDbXXXX classes from the System.Data.OleDb namespace

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring);
```

While at it, remember that Password is a reserved keyword in MS-Access and thus you need square brackets around it

So, a rewrite of your code will be

```
string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["The_patients.Properties.Settings.Users1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
{
    string q = @"select * from Users  
                 where UserName = @Username and [Password] = @Password ";
    using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", this.UserName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", this.Password.Text);
        con.Open();
        using(OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows == true)
               MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully Done");
            else
               MessageBox.Show("Access Denied, password username mismatched"); 

        }
    }
}
```

Notice that disposable objects like connection, commands and readers should be enclosed in a using statement to ensure the correct disposing of these objects.

Comment: Thank you i found that the Connection string was wrong so sorry for that :)

Comment: OK, but still follow the advice about using the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) It is very important to keep your application running and your server responsive.